# R's strptime of a time datetime at midnight (00:00:00) gives NA

Tags: r

R's base `strptime` function is giving me output I do not expect.

This works as expected:

```
strptime(20130203235959, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
# yields "2013-02-03 23:59:59"
```

This too:

```
strptime(20130202240000, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
# yields "2013-02-03"
```

**...but this does not. Why?**

```
strptime(20130203000000, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
# yields NA
```

**UPDATE**

The value `20130204000000` showed up in a log I generated on a Mac 10.7.5 system using the command:

```bsh
➜  ~  echo `date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
20130204000000
```

**UPDATE 2**

I even tried [lubridate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/), which seem to be the recommendation:

```
> parse_date_time(c(20130205000001), c("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
 1 parsed with %Y%m%d%H%M%S
[1] "2013-02-05 00:00:01 UTC"
> parse_date_time(c(20130205000000), c("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
1 failed to parse.
[1] NA
```

...and then funnily enough, it printed out "00:00:00" when I added enough seconds to `now()` to reach midnight:

```
> now() + new_duration(13000)
[1] "2013-02-10 00:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: Why is `"2013-02-03"` seen at the start of the day? Because that's what it's documented to do. See the `format` argument in `?strptime`: "The default for the 'format' methods is '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"' if any component has a time component which is not midnight, and '"%Y-%m-%d"' otherwise."

Comment: The issue is ```000000``` giving me ```NA``` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should use `character` and not `numeric` when I parse my dates:

```r
> strptime(20130203000000, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")    # No!
[1] NA
> strptime("20130203000000", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")  # Yes!
[1] "2013-02-03"
```

The reason for this seems to be that my `numeric` value gets cast to `character`, and I used one too many digits:

```r
> as.character(201302030000)
[1] "201302030000"
> as.character(2013020300000)
[1] "2013020300000"
> as.character(20130203000000)
[1] "2.0130203e+13"       # This causes the error: it doesn't fit "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
> as.character(20130203000001)
[1] "20130203000001"      # And this is why anything other than 000000 worked.
```

---

A quick lesson in figuring out the type you need from the docs: In R, execute `help(strptime)` and see a popup similar to the image below.

- The **red** arrow points to the main argument to the function, but does not specify the type (which is why I just tried `numeric`).
- The **green** arrow points to the type, which is in the document's *title*.

[image]

Comment: Well, doh, `strptime` _expects_ a char.  That really isn't worthy of an accepted answer unless you feel you need the 15 points _that_ badly.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel ```help(strptime)``` just says ```x  An object to be converted.``` so it wasn't really made clear in the docs what the type of ```x``` should be. Also, self-answers don't get points.

Comment: Check the title of that help page: `Date-time Conversion Functions to and from Character`. If you have some C-language heritage as I do, then the `str` immediately makes you click `char`.  That the type description is weak may be a most minor bug you can try to file in R's bugzilla.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for pointing out the title. I just went straight for the argument list lower down. I only started with ```R``` last week [for this](https://class.coursera.org/dataanalysis-001), so hopefully it will all become very obvious to me soon :)

Answer (score 0):

you are essentially asking for the "zeroeth" second, which obviously doesn't exist :)

```
# last second of february 3rd
strptime(20130203235959, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

# first second of february 4rd -- notice this 'rounds up' to feb 4th
    # even though it says february 3rd
strptime(20130203240000, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

# no such second
strptime(20130204000000, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

# 2nd second of february 4th
strptime(20130204000001, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

Comment: The value ```20130204000000``` showed up in a log I generated on a *nix system using the command ```echo `date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"` ```. Dates and times: the bane of all programmers' existence :)

Comment: No, _parsing dates and times from ASCII_ is the bane. Had you had the numeric POSIXct representation...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I parse a lot of external data, and most of it ASCII. See my own answer. I had to use ```character```.